# Does $|x|^{p_1}+|y|^{p_2}\ge(|x|+|y|)^{\max\{p_1,p_2\}}$ or $\frac{|x|^{p_1}}{(|x|+|y|)^{\min\{p_1,p_2\}}}\le 1$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, maxima-minima

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and let $p_1, p_2 >1$. I'm trying to prove that at least one of the inequalities, up to some positive constant, holds true:
$$1)\qquad |x|^{p_1} +|y|^{p_2}\ge (|x|+|y|)^{\max\{p_1, p_2\}};$$

$$2)\qquad \begin{cases}
\frac{|x|^{p_1}}{(|x|+|y|)^{\min\{p_1, p_2\}}}\le 1\\
\frac{|y|^{p_2}}{(|x|+|y|)^{\min\{p_1, p_2\}}}\le 1
\end{cases}.$$

I couldn’t prove any of it so far, could someone please help me with that? Or instead give a counterexample?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. inequality fails by taking $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, $x=2$, and sending $y\to 0$. Inequality reads $4+\text{small} \ge (2+\text{small})^3$.
2. if one holds then clearly the other as well. But now in the first, take $p_1=3$, $p_2=2$, $y=1$ and send $x\to\infty$.

PS to save you the trouble of asking in the future, it's trivial to  graphically find counterexamples using [Desmos.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dlvi7cuwl2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask you if you think that inequality $2)$ fails replacing $1$ with a positive constant? I mean, it would be enough for me to have both the quotients bounded by a positive constant (not necessarily $1$). Thank you in advance.

Comment: @C.Bishop the same counterxample works

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $1)$ fails for $x=y=1.$ The first inequality $2)$ fails for $x=2 $, $y\to 0^+$ and $p_2<p_1.$